# What's the diff between reduceLeft and reduceRight in Scala?

Tags: scala, collections

What's the diff between reduceLeft and reduceRight in Scala?

```
  val list = List(1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1)

  val sum1 = list reduceLeft  {_ + _}   
  val sum2 = list reduceRight {_ + _}

  println { sum2 == sum2 }
```

In my snippet `sum1` = `sum2` = `4`, so the order does not matter here.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

## When do they produce the same result

As Lionel already pointed out, `reduceLeft` and `reduceRight` only produce the same result if the function you are using to combine the elements is associative (this isn't always true, see my note at the bottom). For instance when running `reduceLeft` and `reduceRight` on `Seq(1,2,3)` with the function `(a: Int, b: Int) => a - b` you get a different result.

```
scala> Seq(1,2,3)
res0: Seq[Int] = List(1, 2, 3) 

scala> res0.reduceLeft(_ - _)
res5: Int = -4

scala> res0.reduceRight(_ - _)
res6: Int = 2
```

Why this happens can be made clear if we look at how each of the functions is applied over the list.

For `reduceRight` this is what the calls look like if we were to unwrap them.

```
(1 - (2 - 3))
(1 - (-1))
2
```

For `reduceLeft` the sequence is built up starting from the *left*,

```
((1 - 2) - 3)
((-1) - 3)
(-4)
```

## Tail Recursion

Further because `reduceLeft` is implemented using [Tail Recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_recursion), it will not stack overflow when operating on very large collections (possibly even infinite). `reduceRight` is not tail recursive, so given a collection of large enough size, it will produce a stack overflow.

For instance, on my machine if I run the following I get an Out of Memory error,

```
scala> (0 to 100000000).reduceRight(_ - _)
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
  at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:832)
  at scala.runtime.BoxesRunTime.boxToInteger(BoxesRunTime.java:65)
  at scala.collection.immutable.Range.apply(Range.scala:61)
  at scala.collection.IndexedSeqLike$Elements.next(IndexedSeqLike.scala:65)
  at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:742)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1194)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.reversed(TraversableOnce.scala:99)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.reversed(Iterator.scala:1194)
  at scala.collection.TraversableOnce$class.reduceRight(TraversableOnce.scala:197)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.reduceRight(Iterator.scala:1194)
  at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.reduceRight(IterableLike.scala:85)
  at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.reduceRight(Iterable.scala:54)
  ... 20 elided
```

But if I compute with `reduceLeft` I don't get the OOM,

```
scala> (0 to 100000000).reduceLeft(_ - _)
res16: Int = -987459712
```

You might get slightly different results on your system, depending your JVM default memory settings.

## Prefer left versions

So, because of tail recursion, if you know that `reduceLeft` and `reduceRight` will produce the same value, you should prefer the `reduceLeft` variant. This generally holds true of the other left/right functions, such as `foldRight` and `foldLeft` (which are just more general versions of `reduceRight` and `reduceLeft`).

## When do they *really* always produce the same result

A small note about `reduceLeft` and `reduceRight` and the *Associative Property* of the function you are using. I said that `reduceRight` and `reduceLeft` only produce the same results if the operator is associative. This isn't always true for all collection types. That is somewhat of another topic though, so consult the ScalaDoc, but in short the function you are reducing with needs to be *both* commutative and associative in order to get the same results for *all* collection types.

Comment: The pattern explains it all. Great.

Comment: Great explanation! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Reduce left doesn't always equal the same result as reduce right. Consider an asymmetric function on your array.

Assuming the same result, performance is one obvious difference

See [performance-characteristics](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/collections/performance-characteristics.html)

The data structure is build with constant access time to head and tail. Iterating backwards will perform worse for large lists.

Comment: XOR... You want to say that `list reduceLeft  {_ ^ _}` is not the same as `list reduceRight  {_ ^ _}`?

Comment: Yeah the xor was a bad example but asymmetric function like { _ - _ } will give a different result. e.g. list reduceLeft { _ - _ } = -2 and list reduceRight { _ - _ } = 0

Answer (score -3):

The best way to know the difference is read the source code in library/scala/collection/LinearSeqOptimized.scala:

```
  def reduceLeft[B >: A](f: (B, A) => B): B =
    ......
    tail.foldLeft[B](head)(f)

  def reduceRight[B >: A](op: (A, B) => B): B =
    ...... 
    op(head, tail.reduceRight(op))

  def foldLeft[B](z: B)(f: (B, A) => B): B = {
    var acc = z 
    var these = this              
    while (!these.isEmpty) {      
      acc = f(acc, these.head)    
      these = these.tail          
    }                             
    acc
  }
```

The above is some key part of the code, and you can see reduceLeft is based on foldLeft , while reduceRight is implemented via recursion.

I guess reduceLeft has a better performance.